# setTimeout not working inside jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, timeout

I have some behavior attached to a keyup event in my jQuery plugin. Everything works fine except the function supposed to trigger AFTER the timeout is executed immediately.

```
        //attach keyup event for the searchbox
        self.data('gallery_searchTimeout',null); //to enable a delay on the keypress search event
        $(self).find('.gallery-search').keyup(function(){

            var needle = 'look for me';
            var delay = 2000;

            //if a timer is already set, clear it in favor of our new timer
            if (self.data('gallery_searchTimeout') != undefined) clearTimeout(self.data('gallery_searchTimeout'));

            self.data('gallery_searchTimeout', setTimeout((self.data('search')(self,needle)), delay) );
        });


    var search = function(self,needle) {

        console.log('search called with needle: '+needle);

    };
    self.data('search',search);
```

Comment: Head-up, you probably don't need to wrap self into a jQuery object, so instead of `$(self).find`, just use `self.find`

Comment: The whole design looks overly complicated. You should probably simply keep the context in closure instead of setting functions in data.

Comment: dystroy I thought I had to put functions in data in order to call them later on from outside of the plugin execution flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the function to `setTimeout` instead of calling it.

Change

```
self.data('gallery_searchTimeout', setTimeout((self.data('search')(self,needle)), delay) );
```

to

```
self.data('gallery_searchTimeout', setTimeout(self.data('search').bind(null,self,needle), delay) );
```

or

```
self.data('gallery_searchTimeout', setTimeout(function(){
     self.data('search')(self,needle);
}, delay) );
```

Comment: I like the last suggestion, works brilliant. Thanks.